# Set time to zeroes in LINQ-to-Entities query which includes datetime column

Tags: c#, date, linq-to-entities

I'm not sure if it's possible but I've been trying for half a day to use only date for filtering records in MS SQL database and I get to this question. I'm using Repository pattern so I get all records for my entity like this :

```
var rows = DocumentsRepository.All();
```

The table `Documents` has column `Date` of type datetime, I need to keep the time in the database but when I prepare it for filtering I want to use only the date and if possible to set the hours, minutes, seconds and millisecs to zeroes.

Is it possible and how to do it inside a LINQ?

Comment: So you want to store full timestamps, but query only on dates, is that correct?

Comment: Well at some point I want to be able to use only the dates. So yeah, I guess that quering only the dates will be good enough to do what I need.

Comment: Check out [EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(datetimeObj)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395596.aspx)

Comment: Can't you just create a new DateTime object like `.OrderBy(a => new DateTime(a.DateField.Year, a.DateField.Month, a.DateField.Day))`? I don't have an IDE to test against right now.

Answer (score 1):

I would guess [EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(datetimeObj)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395596.aspx) does the trick if you are using EF in your repository.

```
    IQueryable<Entity> query = query.Where(x => EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(x.CreatedAt) == DateTime.Today);

    var someList = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I couldn't understand from the documentation what exactly `(x.CreatedAt) == DateTime.Now` part is doing?

Comment: I don't think that code will work. Don't you mean `DateTime.Today`?

Comment: @Leron x.CreatedAt was just an example property from the imaginary object Entity for showing how to use the EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(). The part your asking for would return a collection of type 'Entity' that are created today (after edit pointed out by @RoyDictus), regardless of the time of day they are created.